# Finding files in Download Directory

Tags: android, kotlin, download

I am trying to transfer a file from my PC to my app’s local storage, which it doesn’t seem that Android will let me do. I saw that as an alternative, I can email it and then download it. I have then tried to extend my app to find files of that type in the download folder and copy them across.
My problem is that I can’t see any files in the download folder.

I’ve followed other answers and have the following in my AndroidManifest:

I hav looked at a number of questions but none seem to go far enough to resolve this, or people say that its solved but I can't see how it worked.

I am compiling for version 29

My code is then:

```
fun getDownloadedFiles() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), requestPermissionCode)
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>,
grantResults: IntArray) {

super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == requestPermissionCode) {
        if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            val downloadsFolder = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
            if (downloadsFolder != null && downloadsFolder.exists()) {
                val files = downloadsFolder.listFiles()
                for (file in files) {
        // my code to find the files I’m interested in file.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

downloadsFolder gets set to /storage/emulated/0/Download, as expected.

When I run it, it jumps from the line “for (file in files) {“ to the end of the function, presumably saying there are no files, when I know there are. What am I doing wrong please?

Alternatively, is there another way to transfer the files?

Comment: Use the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`) to let the user choose content that is in `Downloads/` (or elsewhere).

Comment: You need to request legacy external storage in application tag of manifest file.

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare, but I know which files I want to see, so I don't want the user to be able to choose them.

Comment: Thank you BlackApps, but when I did this the grant result said that I was denied access.